# Do you still gain weapon type xp when the weapon's xp is maxxed?

Tags: defiance

I've heard a rumor but I can't find anything to back it or show that it is untrue. Once a weapon has hit the max experience it can get, you no longer gain weapon type experience from continuing to use it. Is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is absolutely true, since most weapons only have a slight increase in damage on higher levels they added a way to force you to switch weapons. And that is once the xp bar reaches full you are no longer gaining any weapon exp, and thus gives you no weapon levels. But there is a bonus to it, once your weapon exp is full you kind of "level" your weapon, and it gets a random bonus.

http://defiance.junkiesnation.com/2013/04/09/tips-and-tricks-weapons-guide/

> Weapon Tip 2: When weapon XP bars fill up from using them no more XP will be gained in that weapon skill tree, but the weapon will gain a random bonus to it like +10% DMG from behind.

Comment: Yea its true as Lyrion explained. they added this feature to prevent player from using one weapon and force them to switch weapons. Assuming you got some Legendary weapon some player might use it like 4 ever, so this limitation will make you use different weapons in-order to deal more damage.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can Reset Weapon Mastery Points at Salvage Matrix when you max your XP limit for Ark Salvage that is being calculated based on weapon's rarity.

Comment: And it's fairly cheap now, in the grand scheme of things.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is true, I have been using a maxed Sawed Off Scattergun for a while now and have gained 6 levels with it since it has been maxed.